# Android Is it possible to test Signed App (Staging App) without the verification is done through oAUTH?

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-fit

We are integrating GoogleFit in our existing application. We were able to test in Debug mode. But when we are trying to test using Signed Version of the App (Staging) Google oAuth is not letting to proceed. Its returning RESULT_CANCELED.

Is it because we have not done the oAuth Verification yet?

Comment: release builds sometimes require you to upload the version to google play onto a test track, after installing it from there it behaves like a regular released app.

Comment: Staging build -> We are adding externaltest as a suffix. So this is not technically release build. But this is signed build with proper keystore. I tried adding to firebase and tested through that way. It still behaves the same way. Not progressing the Google Sign in page.

Comment: If you add a suffix you'll have to have credentials for that suffix too because most of them are only valid for a certain package name once it's a release / signed build. If you don't want to have a separate app registered, don't alter the package name

Answer (score 0):

it all comes to the fact SH1 was changed and google can't verify you anymore add your new SH1 generated by your StoreKey this should work

Answer (score 0):

After sometime figured out. It turned out, for externalTest (Staging Build) We were using different sha1 fingerprint. Different than the production one (You have the signing SHA1 from Google Play Store Console) After i entered the new Sha1, everything works fine as expected.